Can `std::filesystem` work on bare-metal?
Recently, I read How does std::filesystem work on every OS?
I know std::filesystem can be used on various OS.
In other words, std::filesystem is a cross-platform library which can be used for accessing files, because the file system has been implemented by the OS vendors.
But what about bare-metal?
AFAIK, bare-metal environment has no function (or very simple) for filesystem.
As the title, can std::filesystem work on bare-metal?

On bare-metal, you are the OS vendor, no?

A library can work in whatever environment it’s written for, same way we’d implement printf to dump to a serial port.

Does the C++ standard library implementation you use provide it? Can you give is a bit more info on what your "bare metal" is?

Have a read of Freestanding and hosted implementations

The question seems slightly off-base: why would you want std::filesystem to work on "bare metal" (I assume a microcontroller)? Typically if you don't have the resources to store an OS, you don't have the resources to store a filesystem either. Perhaps worded better: what would you be using std::filesystem for?

What exactly do you mean by bare metal?  In the traditional usage of that term, filesystems don't exist on bare metal.  Filesystems are themselves an abstraction.  It sounds like you might be asking about a particular computer with particular limitations?

A freestanding implementation isn't required to provide <filesystem>.
Having said that, if there isn't such thing as "a file" or "a directory" on the target, then e.g. exists is really easy to implement:
namespace std {
    bool exists( const std::filesystem::path& p ) { return false; }
}


std::filesystem has been implemented by OS vendors.

Not by vendors of OSs, but by vendors of C++ implementations. Microsoft is a special case, because they sell both, but the Visual C++ team is separate from the Windows team.

When I was at Microsoft, I worked on both the Visual C++ team and the Windows team.  (But that was a special case.)


I know std::filesystem can be used on various OS.

Correct.

because filesystem has been implemented by OS vendors.

Wrong. OS vendors rarely implement std::filesystem or any other C++ standard libraries. It is the creators of C++ compilers (and associated tooling) that implement C++ standard libraries for each OS they want to support.

can std::filesystem work on bare-metal?

Yes, but only in the following sense: if you implement it for your bare-metal, it sure will work.
Good luck with that.
